# How is GitHub So fast?

Tags: performance, github, upload

Before I had even fathomed using GitHub, I used GoogleDrive to share files when working in collaborative projects. But with some projects being many gigabytes large, it often took ~30 minutes to upload them to GoogleDrive.

After learning about GitHub and connecting it to my terminal, I uploaded a ~4 Gigabyte folder which contained all of my project files. I git pushed and within about half a minute the terminal gave me a positive output and told me it had pushed my changes.

No, I had not uploaded the files beforehand and was just pushing changes, this was the first push of my project files.

So my question is; How does GitHub upload files in a matter of minutes, but GoogleDrive and other softwares take ~30 minutes to an hour?

I wonder if it uploads continuously in the background or something like that?